# Vb visual basics console mode is flickering too much. Any way to stop it?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2008

I have been programming for just over half a year now, so sorry for how bad this code is. But i am making pong in vb console mode in 2008. I am doing it for a project at my 6th form that why its in 2008. But when the ball is moving along it i causing the whole thing to flicker. I am using a 2D array with a ticker to move the ball. The code is pretty long and in separate classes so i will put the bit which i think is causing the problem. There is a lot of subs below the last which just move the paddles down and up

```
Module Module1
Public arrfield(79, 11), readkey, secounds, key, score1, score2 As String
Public milliSecond As Integer = 0
Public secound As Integer = 0
Private Tick As New Timers.Timer(1)
Public h As Integer = 39
Public g As Integer = 6
<MTAThread()> _
Sub Main()
    AddHandler Tick.Elapsed, AddressOf ticker
    score1 = 0
    score2 = 0
    Console.WriteLine("Hello and welcome to Russell's pong program!")
    Console.WriteLine("This is a two player game, one person on WSAD and the other person on the arrow keys")
    Console.WriteLine("Press ENTER to start")
    Console.ReadLine()
    fireldsetup()
    field()
    ball1()
    win_lose()
    Paddle1_middle_Paddle2_middle()
End Sub
<MTAThread()> _
Sub ball1()
    Dim run As New ballphysics()
    Dim ballphysics As New Thread(AddressOf run.ball)
    ballphysics.Name = "ballphysics"
    ballphysics.IsBackground = True
    ballphysics.Start()
End Sub
<MTAThread()> _
Sub win_lose()
    Dim run As New win_lose()
    Dim win_lose As New Thread(AddressOf run.win)
    win_lose.Name = "win_lose"
    win_lose.IsBackground = True
    win_lose.Start()
End Sub
Sub fireldsetup()
    For i = 0 To 79
        For j = 0 To 11
            arrfield(i, j) = " "
        Next
    Next
    For i = 0 To 79
        arrfield(i, 1) = "_"
    Next
    For i = 0 To 79
        arrfield(i, 11) = "_"
    Next
    Tick.Enabled = True
End Sub
Sub field()
    Console.Clear()
    Console.WriteLine()
    Console.WriteLine("  " & "Player1" & "                                                             " & "Player2")
    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Green
    Console.WriteLine("  " & score1 & "                               !PONG!                                    " & score2)
    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.White
    Console.WriteLine()
    Console.WriteLine()
    For i = 0 To 79
        Console.Write(arrfield(i, 1))
    Next
    For i = 0 To 79
        Console.Write(arrfield(i, 2))
    Next
    For i = 0 To 79
        Console.Write(arrfield(i, 3))
    Next
    For i = 0 To 79
        Console.Write(arrfield(i, 4))
    Next
    For i = 0 To 79
        Console.Write(arrfield(i, 5))
    Next
    For i = 0 To 79
        Console.Write(arrfield(i, 6))
    Next
    For i = 0 To 79
        Console.Write(arrfield(i, 7))
    Next
    For i = 0 To 79
        Console.Write(arrfield(i, 8))
    Next
    For i = 0 To 79
        Console.Write(arrfield(i, 9))
    Next
    For i = 0 To 79
        Console.Write(arrfield(i, 10))
    Next
    For i = 0 To 79
        Console.Write(arrfield(i, 11))
    Next
End Sub
Private Sub LookForKeyPress()
    Dim k As ConsoleKeyInfo = Console.ReadKey()
    readkey = k.Key.ToString
End Sub
Sub ticker()
    milliSecond += 1
    secound = milliSecond
End Sub
Sub Paddle1_middle_Paddle2_middle()
    fireldsetup()
    arrfield(2, 7) = "│"
    arrfield(2, 6) = "│"
    arrfield(2, 5) = "│"
    arrfield(76, 7) = "│"
    arrfield(76, 6) = "│"
    arrfield(76, 5) = "│"
    field()
    LookForKeyPress()
    If readkey = "S" Then
        readkey = ""
        Paddle1_up1_Paddle2_middle()
    ElseIf readkey = "W" Then
        readkey = ""
        Paddle1_down1_Paddle2_middle()
    ElseIf readkey = "DownArrow" Then
        readkey = ""
        Paddle1_middle_Paddle2_up1()
    ElseIf readkey = "UpArrow" Then
        readkey = ""
        Paddle1_middle_Paddle2_down1()
    Else
        Paddle1_middle_Paddle2_middle()
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it helps but instead of writing everything with on the console from your code you should consider assembling a string and only use console.writeline once.

```
Dim yourStringBuilder As New StringBuilder

yourstringBuilder.Append("yourContent")

Console.WriteLine(yourStringBuilder.ToString())
```

Comment: How would I go about doing that?

Comment: if so create somewhere a StringBuilder. instead of Console.Write use yourstringBuilder.Append(yourContent). instead of Console.WriteLine use yourstringBuilder.AppendLine(yourContent) then when the cycle is finished you simply do Console.WriteLine(yourstringBuilder.ToString())

Comment: but as i said i dont know if this will do any good to your flickering problem but i think it will perform better

Comment: Is at least worth a try =)

Answer (score 0):

Do not use Console.Clear() that is what is causing the flickering. Use [Console.SetCursorPosition(0, 0)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.setcursorposition(v=vs.110).aspx) to set the cursor back at the corner and write over your text.

When you call clear, the user can see the screen being cleared. I also suggest you put a few spaces after you write scrore2 incase the new score is smaller than the old one.

Comment: I have tried this solution before but it cause the field to be written in the wrong way. It gets all jumbled up and after a short time the ball stops still.

Comment: @RussShroom it's a bit difficult to figure out what is your problem without running your code. If you want to remove flickering, you have to stop calling Clear(). I would suggest you start by having just a ball bouncing around and slowly add the rest of the feature one by one to see where the problem lies.